# Devise after_sign_in_path_for works, but redirection doesn't happen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise doesn't redirect to the url provided by `after_sign_in_path_for`.
It actually calls my custom `after_sign_in_path_for` instead. It calculates the url, that I expect it to calculate, but then redirection doesn't happen. It remains at the `sign_in` page, but the actual signing in does not take place.

I've been trying several versions of devise:

```
gem 'devise'
```

and

```
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
```

Same result.

My custom `after_sign_in_path_for`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    str = stored_location_for(resource) || stored_location || root_path
    debugger
    str
end

def stored_location
    session.delete(:return_to)
end

def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end
```

Is being called, it gives proper url, gives `str` exactly as I expect it to give.
Debugger stops at this point...

But after `cont` the page stays at `sign_in`, while however the signing in takes place.

I believe it is not my code issue. It might be a Devise issue. Can anyone, who has it **working**, share with me the exact version of Devise, which works with you.

Comment: Can you confirm that the login info is valid?  `respond_with` will check the resource item for errors before moving on to the provided location, and it will do this after resolving your custom path

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without seeing your server logs.  If `after_sign_in_path_for` is being called and generating the expected URL, then that leaves one possibility:

```
# app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
# POST /resource/sign_in
def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

[The `respond_with` method will act sensibly according to the status of the resource](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/10/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-restful-rendering).  Since it's rendering the `new` template again, it points to some sort of validation error or other problem signing in.

Take a look at the server logs.  Here is a successful sign in and subsequent redirect using the `after_sign_in_path_for` from my app:

```
Started POST "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-18 09:59:27 -0700
[INFO] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:27 -0700] Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
[INFO] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:27 -0700]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DGjs2b3k8BIi62KWCn3u5kx7YxxyR03xkERcgH/ilr0=", "admin"=>{"email"=>"me@mydomain.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
[DEBUG] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:27 -0700]   Admin Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."email" = 'me@mydomain.com' LIMIT 1
[DEBUG] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:27 -0700]    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
[DEBUG] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:27 -0700]    (0.9ms)  UPDATE "admins" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2012-10-18 16:53:19.428068', "current_sign_in_at" = '2012-10-18 16:59:28.076180', "last_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "sign_in_count" = 3, "updated_at" = '2012-10-18 16:59:28.078677' WHERE "admins"."id" = 1
[DEBUG] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:27 -0700]    (9.3ms)  COMMIT
[INFO] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:27 -0700] Redirected to http://localhost:3001/admin/users
[INFO] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:27 -0700] Completed 302 Found in 97ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[INFO] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:28 -0700] 

Started GET "/admin/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-18 09:59:28 -0700
[INFO] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:28 -0700] Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
[DEBUG] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:28 -0700]   Admin Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
[DEBUG] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:28 -0700]   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
[INFO] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:28 -0700]   Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
[INFO] [127.0.0.1] [2012-10-18 09:59:28 -0700] Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 16.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

Are you seeing that redirect?

Comment: Yes. You are quite right. There was a weird validation thing. User could not validate properly, because of StateMachine entanglement. I was trying to fire on a user an event, that is not available from the state he was at. Whatever. It was a deep validation issue. After fixing the statemachine events, it all works.
Thanks!

Comment: Yup, for me it was a user model validation error, that although allowed to log in, didn't allow the user to be updated, hence the redirect to sign_in...